# PHP AES-128-CBC Decoding Issue?

Tags: php, aes

I've been going crazy trying to decode an `AES-128-CBC` encrypted.

The docs from the third-party who encrypt the string.

> The parameters are encrypted using AES 128 with Cipher Block Chaining, using PKCS-7
>   Padding. The decryption algorithm should be initialised with a 16 byte, zero-filled
>   initialization vector, and should use your encryption key (which can be found on the
>   Security page of PayWay Net Shopping Cart setup).

**Example Encrypted Parameters:** `=QzFtdn0%2B66KJV5L8ihbr6ofdmrkEQwqMXI3ayF7UpVlRheR7r5fA6
IqBszeKFoGSyR7c7J4YsXgaOergu5SWD%2FvL%2FzPSrZER9BS7mZGckriBrhYt%2FKMAbTSS8F
XR72gWJZsul9aGyGbFripp7XxE9NQHVMWCko0NlpWe7oZ0RBIgNpIZ3JojAfX7b1j%2F5ACJ79S
VeOIK80layBwCmIPOpB%2B%2BNI6krE0wekvkkLKF7CXilj5qITvmv%2FpMqwVDchv%2FUNMfCi
4uUA4igHGhaZDQcV8U%2BcYRO8dv%2FnqVbAjkNwBqxqN3UPNFz0Tt76%2BP7H48PDpU23c61eM
7mx%2FZh%2Few5Pd0WkiCwZVkSZoov97BWdnMIw5tOAiqHvAR3%2BnfmGsx`

**Example Encryption Key:** `D5cD2CaHd3zfG3C5Apaeyc==`

The code I've tried to use:

```
$encryptedText = '=QzFtdn0%2B66KJV5L8ihbr6ofdmrkEQwqMXI3ayF7UpVlRheR7r5fA6
IqBszeKFoGSyR7c7J4YsXgaOergu5SWD%2FvL%2FzPSrZER9BS7mZGckriBrhYt%2FKMAbTSS8F
XR72gWJZsul9aGyGbFripp7XxE9NQHVMWCko0NlpWe7oZ0RBIgNpIZ3JojAfX7b1j%2F5ACJ79S
VeOIK80layBwCmIPOpB%2B%2BNI6krE0wekvkkLKF7CXilj5qITvmv%2FpMqwVDchv%2FUNMfCi
4uUA4igHGhaZDQcV8U%2BcYRO8dv%2FnqVbAjkNwBqxqN3UPNFz0Tt76%2BP7H48PDpU23c61eM
7mx%2FZh%2Few5Pd0WkiCwZVkSZoov97BWdnMIw5tOAiqHvAR3%2BnfmGsx';

$password = 'D5cD2CaHd3zfG3C5Apaeyc=='
$method = 'AES-128-CBC';
$iv = substr($password, 0, 16); 

$result = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $password, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

return $result;
```

This exact code won't work as the password is made up. But this is basically the result I get:

```
hóuR█\f\x04}wù8¨Ø½5\x02|¹ä\x16;┐¸F;Ã=·Íû\x1A¿┴ô`\x05\x08■▓¡¢|Ù_i=æëÔJ▀ß+Ñc"1ÝÒSÑî²ÚMã\x18°FÅcÃj>│└\x0E¦ï\eêÅZ\fÜ║õê6GC╬Íþ╚É¤?\x11-P^╔öT\x10ÖÈ│,╬¤┼¹op5±órj\x7F\x1D\x10NTªh«@\fÖÚú┤▓╗L┤¼╬1Ç¥æ³\x1Ci R\x1DA8u¥MÀ\x019rmÚ§/~X╔¹\x12]]øÓ PÕopÁ]s‗ \x15Ú$\x0Eo\e\x0F┌äËXû>ÃRr}úýáÞz\x13(Õü\x13╦│\eÿB$ËÁO]¹å‗ÔÓm┴´¦╠`3\x17lPób¼\x15þz\x17/B╝+ÈØ¾´■,8\x1AAÚöÍá}░TFxÛR)[x?k░%z\fWPÉ-┐üð┬kÜÅr┘.ÔkÅ@^QXiH±¡wö!N
```

Non-UTF-8 string... I can't figure what I'm doing wrong... Is it the $iv that's wrong? Going crazy here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to base64 decode the password/secret key before trying to decrypt.

So solution:

```
$encryptedText = '=QzFtdn0%2B66KJV5L8ihbr6ofdmrkEQwqMXI3ayF7UpVlRheR7r5fA6
IqBszeKFoGSyR7c7J4YsXgaOergu5SWD%2FvL%2FzPSrZER9BS7mZGckriBrhYt%2FKMAbTSS8F
XR72gWJZsul9aGyGbFripp7XxE9NQHVMWCko0NlpWe7oZ0RBIgNpIZ3JojAfX7b1j%2F5ACJ79S
VeOIK80layBwCmIPOpB%2B%2BNI6krE0wekvkkLKF7CXilj5qITvmv%2FpMqwVDchv%2FUNMfCi
4uUA4igHGhaZDQcV8U%2BcYRO8dv%2FnqVbAjkNwBqxqN3UPNFz0Tt76%2BP7H48PDpU23c61eM
7mx%2FZh%2Few5Pd0WkiCwZVkSZoov97BWdnMIw5tOAiqHvAR3%2BnfmGsx';

$password = 'D5cD2CaHd3zfG3C5Apaeyc=='
$method = 'AES-128-CBC';
$iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

$result = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, base64_decode($password), OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

return $result;
```